# How to save plots as colorful .eps in octave

Tags: latex, octave, eps

I am using win7 and octave 3.6.4,
when i generate a plot with octave and save as .eps its colors go away.
For example :

```
clf();
surf(peaks);
```

generates following graphic
[image]

But when i run the following codes seperately

```
saveas (1,"test.eps")  or print (1,"test.eps") or print -deps test.eps
```

to save the graphic as .eps and import it into latex it becomes grayscale.
[image]

Comment: that's a weird problem. Did you try to open the eps file in another program to check if it has colour? Are you sure the problem is not in the LaTeX side?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
print -depsc test.eps
```

or

```
print -color -depsc test.eps
```

if the first one doesn't work.

**EDIT**:

Which graphics toolkit are you using? with `gnuplot`, it works just fine for me (Octave 3.6.2, Win XP) using the `-eps` flag.

Comment: `pkg load gnuplot`? Don't you mean `graphics_toolkit gnuplot`?

Comment: No, I did mean `pkg load gnuplot`, but actually it was when using the `qt` graphics toolkit which gave me errors when trying to print to eps. Loading the `gnuplot` package got rid of the errors, but I was still unable to print. I then switched to the `gnuplot` graphics toolkit and I was able to print successfully. I will remove this from my answer as it's irrelevant. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
print -dtex test.tex
```

Octave automatically exports your figure into LaTeX/Color EPS figure, with LaTeX fonts.

Comment: What do you do with the output .tex file?